# Making System Calls with Options

Tags: elixir

I understand that I can do simple things like `System.cmd("echo", ["hello"])` but suppose I wanted to do something like run a Ruby process

Normally in the shell I could do something like: `ruby -e 'puts "hello world"`

I've tried a bunch of variations of something similar to:

`System.cmd("ruby", ["-e", "'puts \"hello world\"'"])` without much luck

I can call down the the Erlang `os` module, but that doesn't seem ideal as I need to explicitly split my string into characters and recast it as well as figure out how to capture the exit code in addition to the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.cmd("ruby", ["-e", "puts \"hello world\""])
```

seems to work :)

Comment: Oh jeez, hours spent just to figure out quotes would be added for me. Thanks!

Comment: System.cmd is much more like exec that the ruby version. It never goes through the shell so you don't have to do shell cmd line quoting. This is both good and bad. You can't do I/O redirection, but it is slightly more secure.